# Array is not accessible in this program in android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have declared an array address globally and putting the data in this array from the following code

```
    DatabaseReference rootRe = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    count=0;
    for( int i = 0 ; i<base.length;i++){
        DatabaseReference assaultRef = rootRe.child(base[i]);


        ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String latlng = ds.child("liststring").child("0").getValue(String.class);
                    //address.add(latlng);
                    address[count] = latlng;
                    Log.i("Address","Address["+count+"]= "+address[count]);
                    count++;

                    //Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, address.length, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
        };
        assaultRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
    }
    //for (int i = 0 ; i<10;i++)
    Log.i("Address[0]","Address[0]= "+address[0]);
```

My problem is that before the toast it is showing values in address and but in the last Log.i() address value is showing null.

Comment: Please share your database structure. There is no need to use that for loop.

Answer (score 0):

The `Log.i("Address[0]","Address[0]= "+address[0]);` method is invoked as soon as you register the listener, but the array population is done when the data changes, hence resulting in invocation of onDataChange() method. Which must happen after the registration. A good way to debug this is to add print statements in onDataChange method and after the log.i() methods and observe the order of invocation of the methods.

Comment: yes definetly ,log.i is invoke before the print statement so now what should i do to get the data in log.i also

Comment: It depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to do some processing after data is set in the array, you should do that in ondatachanged method.